# How To Use Run Anything in Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android-studio

[image]

**Android Studio 3.4 New Functionality Added But How to Use This ?**

Comment: It look just like terminal to me where you can run commands , just we are getting auto complete suggestions  below

Answer (score 11):

I Messed around with it some time and here is what I found .

You can use it to run commands for

1. Gradle task
2. Run Configurations
3. Recent Projects

You will get auto complete suggestions for the commands you are typing . It will also save the history of all the commands executed .

( From what I see you can run any terminal command but you are not gonna get autocomplete suggestions for other types of commands)

**Shortcut** : Double <kbd>ctrl</kbd>

You can also filter what commands to run by clicking on the filter icon on top

[image]

Comment: `From what I see you can run any terminal command` I don't think that's true, I added a script to my environment path and `run anything` did not pick it up, even after a restart. Could you expand on this point? Is there maybe a path variable that can be configured in Android Studio?